# Help to understand the operating logic of the Bosch charger

Tags: batteries, digital-logic, schematics, surface-mount, charger

I ask for your help to:

1. determine, if possible, the type of transistor T5, T7 (SMD code: MK3C).
2. help me understand the operating role of the set T5, T7 and R23, R33 in the circuit (it's like a logical port type AND, but I do not understand how it works).
3. help me understand why the feedback control of the battery voltage is made by R38 + R43 before the diode SK34F and not after.

To simplify the repair I made a schematic by reverse engineering; diagram and other photos are below.

[image: GAL18V20 (C) - Schematic Final]

[image: Components Reference]

[image: ic2 : ST microcontroller]
the microcontroller is the same as STM8S003F3
[Datasheet](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm8s003f3.html)

Comment: Have you tried to measure the T5 and T7 and check if they are BJT's or MOSFET? And no markings on IC2? And what software did you use to draw this schematic?

Comment: The T5 and T7 are shortcuts,i can't measure them, for ic2 it's a ST microcontroller, i use Splan 7.0 to do the schematic

Comment: Guess, T5, T7 current limiter /switches? PNP BJT or MOS-FET P ? Probably, logic level MOS-FET-P because of high-value resistor 4k7 driving. There is probably multilevel voltage batteries, so also different level of current? Some batteries are coded (with a known resistor (COD).

Comment: i have try some combination : dual NPN : not work / dual PNP : work well / dual N-Mosfet : Not work / dual P-Mosfet : not tested (I do not have) but i think it will be work

Comment: what you suggest to me, uses two PNP or P-Mosfet

Comment: Here, for my thought, I suggest the use of P-Mosfet. As I said the driving resistor (4k7) seems "high" for a PNP (except if it is a Darlington ?). But one question remains. Why two in serial?

Comment: Sorry, i did not find any reference in this https://smd.yooneed.one/code4d4b.html

Comment: “Q3 - Why voltage sample before Diode, not close to Battery?” My guess: to protect MCU to receive voltage in their Analog input pins, when battery is connected and charged is not powered. Also, voltage drop in SK34 is small and I x deltaV curves are known, which could be compensated by MCU algorithm for higher precision.

Comment: “Q2 - About T5 & R33” That might depend of MCU’s algorithm,but it would be possible to turn-on T5 and see voltage developing in R43. If battery is properly attached, R43 voltage raises less. Then R33 can be bypassed by T7 and again voltage should be as expected by a good battery. If voltage Variation with charging current is too high, maybe battery is “not good” (high internal resistance). This might be a reason to use 2 switches - [1] enable charging phase and [2] estimate internal resistance. MOSFETs are your #1 choice as they will not have voltage drop as BJT, that could affect MCU.

Comment: “Q1 Transistor type” - I would go for a P-channel MOSFET, that seems to be the safest candidate here. You said a PNP BJT worked, but you should check if the Vce voltage drop would affect battery identification and battery health monitoring. If it works good for you, then a PNP may be cheaper and easier to find.

Comment: Good evening for all, thank you, Mr EJE for your answer, as you say, actually with the PNP the charger takes longer than expected to detect that the battery is fully charged